# error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.String)

Tags: android, sql, android-room

Face the following error while writing a query for a table in Android Room Database using Java.

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.String). LiveData<List<String>>

Query:

```
@Query("SELECT timeStamp FROM myTable")
LiveData<List<String>> getAllTimeStamps();
```

I notice that this error doesn't occur for Lists holding custom classes.

Edit: It works after changing query to this

```
@Query("SELECT CAST(timeStamp AS TEXT) FROM myTable")
```

Comment: What was the data type in your table!?

Comment: Try `@Query("SELECT CAST(timeStamp AS TEXT) FROM myTable")`

Comment: @GobuCSG It is `String timeStamp;`

Comment: Okay,. Can you share your lib details

Comment: `compileSdk 32` `Gradle Plugin Version 7.2.1` `Gradle Version 7.3.3`  `def room_version = "2.3.0"` @GobuCSG